# Fortran choice of format to enhance code execution time

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a code which starts with three arrays of values which are initialized in the beginning of the code. For a different runs, I have to go into the code to make an explicit changes on these initial values.
Since this is very frustrating and time consuming, I have decided to modify the code such that the code reads the initial values from a text file instead.

Although I successfully made a change, now the code runs much much slower (at least factor 20).

When I initialized the array explicitly in the code, the arrays looked something like

array1 = {0.001,0.002,0.034,...}
array2 = {42D4, 36D4, 72D4, 10D5, ...}.

and I have tried reading these array values from a text file using

Format(E8.2) or Format(D8.2) or Format(F8.2).

I am guessing that the way I read the values from the file using these format has to do with the immense reduction in the code speed?

Is this true? If not, what do I need to do?
If yes, how should I modify the format so that my code runs at a similar speed as before?

Comment: Please share with us some of your works.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to argue if the reading takes a big part of the runtime in your code. We can't know, because we can't see the code. But if yes then:

As said many, many times before, you are not going to get good performance with text files. The format you set for reading is irrelevant, the runtime library has to do a lot of processing to convert the string to a number in the computer's memory.

The way to significantly speed the I/O operations is to use unformatted (binary) data files.

Notably, formats you tried

```
Format(E8.2)
Format(D8.2)
Format(F8.2)
```

are all **completely equivalent** for input. Not only their speed. Their meaning is for input completely equivalent.